# approximate identities for convolution with measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Convolution makes $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C})$ into an associative algebra that has no identity, but that does have an "approximate identity" in the sense that for any sequence $\varphi_1, \varphi_2,...$ of nonnegative $L^1$ functions with $\int \varphi_k~d\lambda=1$ and $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\varphi_k ~~d\lambda(x)  =0~~~\text{for any }\epsilon>0$$ and any $f\in L^1$, we have $ \varphi_k \ast f \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ (where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure).

**Is the same true (and in what sense?) if we replace $f$ with a Borel probability measure which is not necessarily absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure?**

I.e. with $\varphi_k$ as above, define $$(\varphi_k \ast \mu)(y) := \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \varphi_k(y-x)d\mu(x).$$  Do we have $$(\varphi_k \ast \mu) \lambda \rightarrow \mu$$ in some sense? Still another way to ask it is whether we have $$(\varphi_k \lambda) \ast \mu \rightarrow \mu$$ in some sense (where this $\ast$ means convolution of measures)?